# Kotlin: Symbol is declared in module 'jdk.internal.opt' which does not export package 'jdk.internal.joptsimple.internal'

Tags: java, kotlin, java-11, java-module

My enthusiasm to use Strings.isNullOrEmpty in Kotlin 1.3 importing jdk.internal.joptsimple.internal.Strings.isNullOrEmpty has been clouded by Kotlin throwing the exception in the title. (Tested with the latest versions of JDK11 and JDK12)

My main.kt file

```
import jdk.internal.joptsimple.internal.Strings.isNullOrEmpty

fun main() {
    print("Enter your name : ")
    val userName = readLine()!!
    if (isNullOrEmpty(userName)) {
        println("Hello, $userName")
    }
}
```

When I try to run this, build fails with these messages IntelliJ console:

```
Error:(1, 41) Kotlin: Symbol is declared in module 'jdk.internal.opt' which does not export package 'jdk.internal.joptsimple.internal' Error:(7, 9) Kotlin: Symbol is declared in module 'jdk.internal.opt' which does not export package 'jdk.internal.joptsimple.internal'
```

Wondering if I'm missing or doing anything wrong here...

Comment: Do you mean to use `if (userName.isNullOrEmpty()) { ... }`?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by changing the code to

```
fun main() {
    print("Enter your name : ")
    val userName = readLine()!!
    if (!userName.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        println("Hello, $userName")
    }
}
```